# Rgd: Dynamic adding HTML by jQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had the following code

```
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment


                $(wrapper).append('<div class="row" style="margin:20px;">'); //add input box


                $(wrapper).append('<select name="promotion_item[]" class="form-control" />'); //add input box


                $(wrapper).append('<option value="" disabled>---- MEALS ----</option>'); //add input box


                $(wrapper).append('<option value="fish_burger">Fish Burger</option>'); //add input box

                $(wrapper).append('<option value="chicken_salad">Chicken Salad</option>'); //add input box


                $(wrapper).append('<option value="1">Banji 300</option><option value="2">Brownie:box of 6</option></select>'); //add input box


                $(wrapper).append('</div>'); //add input box


            $(wrapper).append('<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

When I click the button that link to this code, it does append to the div.

But the select tag close immediately when I check via inspect element. so my output was something like this for the select part, it close my select tag immediately after it open. I wonder what is wrong with my append code.

```
<select name="promotion_item[]" class="form-control" /></select>
```

**Thanks**

Comment: I don't really get your question, but see, that you append options to wrapper, not to selct. And new "click" event you have to define each time you append such link.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use broken HTML like this in place of `append()`, because it immediately calculates the HTML and it gets filled. Instead build a HTML string and then append. This way please:

```
var finalHTML = "";
finalHTML += '<div class="row" style="margin:20px;">'; //add input box
finalHTML += '<select name="promotion_item[]" class="form-control" />'; //add input box
finalHTML += '<option value="" disabled>---- MEALS ----</option>'; //add input box
finalHTML += '<option value="fish_burger">Fish Burger</option>'; //add input box
finalHTML += '<option value="chicken_salad">Chicken Salad</option>'; //add input box
finalHTML += '<option value="1">Banji 300</option><option value="2">Brownie:box of 6</option></select>'; //add input box
$(wrapper).append(finalHTML + '</div>'); //add input box
```

**Output: https://jsbin.com/yihomekidi/1**